Firebase Analytics parameters
I have a flutter (ios & android) project. I'm trying to learn how to use Firebase Analytics. Everything is working fine in DebugView and I can see all the data I send.
But I don't understand how to read data out of the DebugView.
For example, using this function from the firebase_analytics flutter package :
Future<void> logShare({
  required String contentType,
  required String itemId,
  required String method,
  Map<String, Object>? parameters,
})

In the firebase interface, in Analytics > Events, when I click on the "share" event, where can I see the contentType or the method logs?


You need to register those parameters in Firebase UI via Custom definitions. They are custom event parameters.
